# What is the number of channels of input audio mel spectrogram?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, speech-recognition

What is the number of channels of input audio mel spectrogram? For example, in CV we always have 3 input channels on RGB picture. But what about audio?